# Case insensitive indexing in Postgres with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Consider a declarative SQLAlchemy model with an indexed `String` field:

```
class User(Base):
    name = Column(String(100), index=True, nullable=False)
```

The `name` field is case sensitive, meaning the original case should be preserved, but efficient **case-insensitive** queries on the index should be supported.

What's the best way to achieve this and implement in SQLAlchemy?

Queries can use `lower()` if needed

```
session.query(User).filter_by(name=lower('SOME_name'))
```

but it doesn't matter too much, as long as the solution is elegant and performant.

Queries using `ILIKE` and Postgres-level `lower()` are unacceptable due to performance requirements, they've been tested and do not perform fast enough on large tables for my use case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a [functional index](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#functional-indexes) that indexes the expression `LOWER(name)`:

```
Index('idx_user_name_lower', func.lower(User.name))
```

With the index in place queries such as

```
session.query(User).filter(func.lower(User.name) == 'SOME_name'.lower())
```

may perform better, if `LOWER(name)` has high cardinality.

You could then encapsulate handling the lowercasing in a [custom comparator](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#building-custom-comparators):

```
# Verbatim from the documentation
class CaseInsensitiveComparator(Comparator):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return func.lower(self.__clause_element__()) == func.lower(other)

class User(Base):
    ...
    @hybrid_property
    def name_insensitive(self):
        return self.name.lower()

    @name_insensitive.comparator
    def name_insensitive(cls):
        return CaseInsensitiveComparator(cls.name)
```

The comparator will apply `func.lower()` to both sides behind the scenes:

```
session.query(User).filter_by(name_insensitive='SOME_name')
```

is equivalent to

```
session.query(User).filter(func.lower(User.name) == func.lower('SOME_name'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough reply! When you say "may perform better" can I expect performance that is on par with regular indexed querying?

Comment: Yes, it should perform as well, given that the statistics and the query are such that the index is used.

Comment: For the record, this is supported since SQLAlchemy 0.8.0